# Reading a DOCX file from stream

Tags: c#, web-services, stream, docx

I wrote the following code for posting two file (an XML and a DOCX file) into a webservice:

```
public void postMultipleFiles(string url, string[] files)
    {
        string boundary = "----------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        httpWebRequest.KeepAlive = true;
        httpWebRequest.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        Stream memStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        byte[] boundarybytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n");
        string formdataTemplate = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\";\r\n\r\n{1}";
        string headerTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"\r\n Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n";
        memStream.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);
        for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
        {
            string header = string.Format(headerTemplate, "file" + i, files[i]);
            //string header = string.Format(headerTemplate, "uplTheFile", files[i]);
            byte[] headerbytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header);
            memStream.Write(headerbytes, 0, headerbytes.Length);
            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(files[i], FileMode.Open,
            FileAccess.Read);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead = 0;
            while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
            {
                memStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            memStream.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);
            fileStream.Close();
        }
        /*AJ*/
        httpWebRequest.ContentLength = memStream.Length;
        Stream requestStream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();
        memStream.Position = 0;
        byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[memStream.Length];
        memStream.Read(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length);
        memStream.Close();
        requestStream.Write(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length);
        requestStream.Close();
        try
        {
            WebResponse webResponse = httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            Stream stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            response.InnerHtml = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            response.InnerHtml = ex.Message;
        }
        httpWebRequest = null;
    }
```

At the webservice I retrieve the same as following:

```
public string MultiFilePost()
{
    string xmls = "";
    string txt = "";
    XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();

    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream != null)
    {

        StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream);
        /*First File*/
        Stream xmlStream = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0].InputStream;
        StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(xmlStream);
        xmls = rd.ReadToEnd();
        /*Second File*/
        Stream txtStream = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[1].InputStream;
        rd = new StreamReader(txtStream);
        txt = rd.ReadToEnd();
    }

    return xmls;
}
```

And thus I get the input streams to string. I can convert the string "xmls" into an XmlDocument object, but in the string txt I receive some sort of string and I need a way to handle it as XmlDocument handles XML files.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [XmlDocument.Load Method (Stream)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e48zttz7.aspx):

```
// First file
var xmlStream = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0].InputStream;
var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.Load(xmlStream);

// The same code for the second file processing.
// Second file
var wordDocStream = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[1].InputStream;
var wordXmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
wordXmlDocument.Load(wordDocStream);
```

## Update

To work with Word documents:

- [OpenXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/bb265236.aspx)
- [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I did this but i need to handle the docx file the same way, thats my question

Comment: @AJ, What do you mean by "handling"?

Comment: I need to know if there exists any class like XmlDocument to handle Xml. And I want to read the contents of the word, say into some string.

Comment: (+1 it was informative); OR can it be generalized to receive any file type.eg: zip, doc, txt, etc